# how to loading part of layout dynamically

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor

how can i have a section (for example a sidebar) that will load at the **first** time in the layout depends on user's login information. and become part of the layout and do not need to post it back every time. and also do not need to read it from @viewBag because changes in sidebar (opened and closed tabs of sidebar by the user) will revert to it's defaults! and of course not using RenderSection() because i have to create that section in every views!
my question is: how can i dynamically add a simple `<div>....</div>` tag to the layout at runtime without using @viewBag or rendersection?

Answer (score 0):

In your layout, you can have an optional section:

```
@RenderSection("OptionalContent", required: false)
```

Then you can create the section in just the views that you want.

Comment: using Rendersection is not a good idea for this scenario because 1) i have to create that section in every views 2) it would be post and post back every time that user navigate to another page. do you have another idea? thanks!

Comment: You don't have to create the section in every view at all. That's what required:false is for. I'm also not sure what you mean by "post back every time the user navigates to another page". There is no post unless the section consists of form controls and it's inside a form. I think you've got your terminology wrong. Explain some more about what you're trying to achieve and don't try pre-empting a solution. Then, it might be easier to give you a workable solution.

Comment: thanks and apologise. because i did not knew that _Layout and view will mix together by the razor engine and then will post for the client. i thought _layout will not post every time that user send a request and this is content (view) that will refresh at all. therefore i was seeking for a solution to keep layout static and prevent from refreshing layout at any request.